ERROR Error: NG0500: During hydration Angular expected <html> but found <meta>
When runing my Angular 17 app I'll get in the console two errors with a part of error message being:
ERROR Error: NG0500: During hydration Angular expected <html> but found <meta>.

Angular expected this DOM:

<app-root _nghost-ng-c1019702276="">
  <html lang="en">…</html>  <-- AT THIS LOCATION
  …
</app-root>

Actual DOM is:

<app-root _nghost-ng-c1019702276="">
  <meta _ngcontent-ng-c1019702276="" charset="UTF-8">…</meta>  <-- AT THIS LOCATION
  …
</app-root>

Note: attributes are only displayed to better represent the DOM but have no effect on hydration mismatches.

The issue is propably somehow connected to app.component.html since it's first bunch of lines look like this:
<!-- UŻYWAJ BULMA DO GOTOWYCH KOMPONENTOW-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">

but if I delete  then I'll get a similar error:
(Part of the error message after deleting )
Angular expected this DOM:

<app-root _nghost-ng-c563235177="">
  <html lang="en">…</html>  <-- AT THIS LOCATION
  …
</app-root>

Actual DOM is:

<app-root _nghost-ng-c563235177="">
  <link _ngcontent-ng-c563235177="" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulm…">…</link>  <-- AT THIS LOCATION
  …
</app-root>

This is my app.component.html:
<!-- UŻYWAJ BULMA DO GOTOWYCH KOMPONENTOW-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-item" href="">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
      </a>
  
      <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  
    <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
      <div class="navbar-start">
        <a class="navbar-item">
          Home
        </a>
  
        <a class="navbar-item" href="Dashboard">
          DASHBOARD
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>


</html>


And my app.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { APIConnectionService } from '../../APIConnectionService/api-connection.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Orch_FrontAngu_Praca';

  constructor(private API_COMM : APIConnectionService) {}

}


What can be the reason of the problem here?

For anyone with the same problem. I fixed this by removing ,  and the same with body and head. If you're using Bulma like me then put  in the index.html in src folder

I encountered the same issue and my problem came form the fact that the "index.html" already have
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your title</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

Then, the index put the code of the app.component via . So if you have the same start of code in it, it brakes everything.
So try deleting
<!-- UŻYWAJ BULMA DO GOTOWYCH KOMPONENTOW-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

from your app.component and it should work.

use english in comments
